# class in header file gives undefined reference error

Tags: c++, oop, compiler-errors, dev-c++

I am new in c++ and have a problem that I could not solve. I wrote a very simple class and put it in a header file. Below are the files:

point.h:

```
// point.h
#include <iostream>

#ifndef _POINT_H_
#define _POINT_H_
using namespace std;

class Point{
    private:
        double x;
        double y;
    public:
        void generate(double a, double b);
        void print();
};
#endif
```

point.cpp:

```
// point.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "point.h"
using namespace std;

void Point::generate(double a, double b) {
    x = a;
    y = b;
} 

void Point::print() {
    cout << x << endl;
    cout << y << endl;
}
```

main.cpp:

```
// main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "point.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
    Point A;
    A.generate(1,2);
    A.print();
    return 0; 
}
```

Every time I compile main.cpp I get the error:

```
main.cpp:(.text+0x30): undefined reference to `Point::generate(double, double)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x3c): undefined reference to `Point::print()'
[Error] ld returned 1 exit status
```

What have I done wrong? Hope for answers ;).

Greetings,
Gerald

Comment: how you do compile (and link) ?

Comment: for compiling i use dev-c++. what do you mean by link? is it not sufficient just to compile and run the main.cpp?

Comment: you have two translation units (aka .cpp) that are compiled seperately and need to be linked

Comment: how do i do that?

Comment: i am reading a totorial ... and there the author does not mention anything about linking.

Comment: Did you add `point.cpp` to your project?

Comment: you mean in main.cpp?

Comment: like #include <point.cpp>?

Comment: No, no. You shouldn't do that. Only include header files. The project you have in dev-c++ should contain two `.cpp` files. `main.cpp` and `point.cpp`.

Comment: yes it has. i included both in the project.

Comment: Can you see the compilers command line or lines? It's probably `g++ <something>` or similar

Comment: now it worked. i put everything in a project and compiled and run the main.cpp and it seems to work. is it correct?

Comment: It sounds correct - but wasn't that what you already had done?

Comment: well no. I did not put everything in a project.

Comment: @Gerald Now I'm confused ... :-)